# Please review this faster way to input tags into filters

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, usability, filtering

Make *Enter* behave like a normal form. Currently it just auto-completes tags (like *Tab*). It should add the selected tag to the list, clear the box and let you continue adding more tags.

Here's what you need to do to add two tags to a filter list now:

```
tag1 -> Tab -> tag2 -> Tab -> Tab -> Enter/Space
```

Notice the two superfluous Tabs.

Here's what I'm proposing:

```
tag1 -> Enter -> tag2 -> Enter
```

Not only is this faster, but for the 90% case of just adding a single tag to the list it's 2x as fast!

```
tag1 -> Enter
```

vs.

```
tag1 -> Tab -> Tab -> Enter
```

Comment: You are using the wrong UI :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand this. I just added a tag to a question like so:

click Edit

<kbd>tab</kbd> [now at post body]

<kbd>tab</kbd> [now at tag field]

<kbd>end</kbd> [moves to end of tag field]

{type enough chars to match the tag I want}

<kbd>enter</kbd> [completes tag]

<kbd>enter</kbd> [submits]

Enter does exactly what you describe, or maybe I'm not understanding what you wrote.

Comment: it now works as you describe. that was not the behavior when I posted it. great, I'm happy, thanks.